# How to auto-arrange/clean-up files for ALL folders in OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, finder

I have figured out how to make folders auto arrange their contents. This is achieved in Finder->View->Show View Options (or cmd+J).

From the newly opened window, setting the arrange by dropdown will set the folders behavior from then on. But it is only for the folder this menu was opened in. How do I set this as a Finder rule for all directories?

**EDIT**
I am using Mountain Lion - 10.8.2
I don't have a 'Use as Defaults' button in my view panes - here's a screen grab:

[image]

Comment: I find this particularly annoying as well. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: When you go to a non-dynamic folder like downloads or documents you should see the "Use as defaults" button.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you select Use as Defaults from the view options panel, Finder will use those settings as defaults for all folders that don't have folder-specific settings stored in .DS_Store files.

[image]

You can clear the folder-specific settings by running `sudo find / -name .DS_Store -delete && killall Finder`. It also [resets other view options, resets the positions of icons, and deletes Spotlight comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69467/consequences-of-deleting-ds-store/69722#69722).

Comment: I don't have a Use as Defaults button... I'll upload a screencap to my question.

Comment: It's not shown in column view. AFAICT, new column view windows use the same arrange by (`FXPreferredGroupBy`) and sort by (`StandardViewOptions:ColumnViewOptions:ArrangeBy`) modes.

Comment: @drewwyatt To show 'Use as Defaults': Finder > (in sidebar) Click your home folder > (menu bar) View > Show View Options

Comment: Still works in Yosemite

Comment: This does not work anymore (Catalina). The clear terminal function just throws out `Operation not permitted` and the `Use as Defaults` does literally NOTHING whatsover

Comment: It doesn't work for the MacOS Big Sur v11.3.1 either

Comment: Works in MacOS 13 Ventura. Just need to open and change setting to have the button enabled