# How to set Finder default View Options for all folders

Tags: terminal, finder, macos-catalina

**Goal:** I want to set the `View Options` for ALL of my Finder folders.

As far as I understand it, the systems saves any `View Options` changes inside that folder, and if the folder doesn't have any settings saves, it will use the `Use as Defaults` that you specify in any `View Options`.

1. I tried cleaning all the folders with commands like `sudo find / -name .DS_Store -delete && killall Finder` which just throws many `Operation not permitted` errors.
2. I tried clicking the `Use as Defaults` button in any `Show View Options` which literally does less than nothing.

(I used this linked as reference to the above steps: [How to auto-arrange/clean-up files for ALL folders in OSX Mountain Lion](https://superuser.com/questions/560411/how-to-auto-arrange-clean-up-files-for-all-folders-in-osx-mountain-lion))

Any idea how to solve this problem? Pretty pissed off with such a basic system setting being such a pain. I am a programmer, but you seriously shouldn't have to run terminal commands just to change folder views.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with asking here, but you may find an answer more quickly in the future by using https://askdifferent.com . You can search there for an answer to this issue, but please don't double-post on both sites.  See some possible answers at https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=set+default+view+options+finder